# Issue in adding new value in ArrayList at 0th position

Tags: android, list, kotlin, arraylist

I have ArrayList of my model/pojo class. Which has below values which I am getting in my logcat :

> BatteryDetailsHistory(dates=10 01 2022, dateNumber=10, chargeOverTime=94, avgTemperature=21.9385, averageChargeDischarge=-2.1234)

Now, here at specific situation I have to add one value of the object BatteryDetailsHistory at 0th position in the arraylist of this model/pojo.

So, I have done it as below :

```
var objNew = list[0]
objNew.averageChargeDischarge = "0"
list.add(0, objNew)
```

But after that What I am getting is as below :

> BatteryDetailsHistory(dates=10 01 2022, dateNumber=10, chargeOverTime=94, avgTemperature=21.9385, averageChargeDischarge=0)

> BatteryDetailsHistory(dates=10 01 2022, dateNumber=10, chargeOverTime=94, avgTemperature=21.9385, averageChargeDischarge=0)

You can see I have tried changing the value of **averageChargeDischarge to 0**
But after adding new object of pojo/model to my **list**, I am getting both the data in list with values 0 for **averageChargeDischarge**

What might be the issue ?

Comment: It's not clear to me what's going wrong here, please provide the expected output vs what you are actually getting.

Comment: @DevWithZachary I want to add same object at position 0 of list with averageChargeDischarge value as 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want just change a property of the first object in the list, you can access it by index:

```
 list[0].averageChargeDischarge = "0"
```

If you want to preserve the first object with its initial data in the list, then you need to make a copy of it, e.g. create a new object:

```
// If object(BatteryDetailsHistory) is a data class
val objNew = list[0].copy(averageChargeDischarge = "0")
list.add(0, objNew)

// If object(BatteryDetailsHistory) is not a data class
val objOld = list[0]
val objNew = BatteryDetailsHistory(/*copy all properties from objOld*/, averageChargeDischarge = "0")
list.add(0, objNew)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you are dealing with one object.

Suppose you have a list with an instance of `SomeObject` in it, which we will call `SomeObject1`:

```
[SomeObject1]
```

Your first line of code, gets a *reference* to `SomeObject1`:

```
var objNew = list[0]
```

So `objNew` is a reference to `SomeObject1`. And now you change a field in `SomeObject1`:

```
objNew.averageChargeDischarge = "0"
```

So now `SomeObject1` has `averageChargeDischarge` equal to `"0"`.
And then you go insert that *same* object back into the list:

```
list.add(0, objNew)
```

And your list looks like this now:

```
[SomeObject1, SomeObject1]
```

You never had two instances of the object, you always only ever had one of them. This is why it appears to show up twice.

Comment: Please suggest the better solution also with cause of issue.